# How to handle type hinting errors from external libraries?

Tags: python, types, variadic-functions, type-hinting, typechecking

I'm using VSCode with the following settings:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
},
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict",
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0111"
],
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true
```

Whenever I use a package I have installed via pip, there are some hint errors (red underline) when calling a function or method.

For example:

```
from slack.web.client import WebClient

def send_message(client: WebClient, channel:str, text:str) -> None:
    res = client.chat_postMessage(
        channel=channel,
        text=text
    )
```

I get the following message from pylance:

> Type of "chat_postMessage" is partially unknown.
> Type of "chat_postMessage" is "(*, channel: str, **kwargs: Unknown) -> (Future[Unknown] | SlackResponse)"

I do get similar messages when using numpy

```
import numpy as np

array = np.linspace(0,5,5)
```

> Type of "array" is partially unknown.
> Type of "array" is "ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]

Is there a way to follow the strict typing rule in this case? Or are there some additional settings i have to make to ignore these kind of type-hint errors?